# How to write a unit test for a stopwatch?

Tags: c++, windows, unit-testing, time

I have a class which measures the time between calling `Start` and `Stop`. I have created a unit test that sleeps using `boost::this_thread::sleep` between `Start` and `Stop` and I test that the result is near the time slept.

However, this test fails on our build agent but not our development machines. The problem is: How do I know whether this is an actual problem of the stopwatch or if it's a "problem" that the build agent (running some other processes, being a virtual machine) might sleep longer than I told it to?

So the question: Is there a robust way to write something like "Do something that takes exactly x seconds?"

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no way to test something like this reliably on a non-realtime system. The way to go would be to wrap the APIs for getting the system-time that your stop-watch uses and mock them in the tests.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the operating system you're using. On systems that supports multi-programming, the running time of your thread is not deterministic. On some real-time systems however, it's almost accurate if your thread is of top priority. You should be able to disable the interrupt to simulate that case, because your thread will not be preempted by OS scheduler.

Answer (score 1):

Take the system time before and after the sleep and refer only to the difference between these times and not to the time you slept.

Answer (score 1):

What is the resolution of your stopwatch? If you need to be accurate by seconds then sleeping for 3 seconds and seeing if you are between 2.9 and 3.1 will work for you. If you need mili/nano second accuracy you should just use timestamp mocks as suggestd in the first reply.